# Is it OK to have separate column in Audit table to store column name to reflect what changes were made

Tags: sql, postgresql, audit

Is it a good practice to store column name to represent what were the changes made in a data in parent table which led to trigger the audit.

Ex :-

```
create table employee
(
emp_id character varying(10),
fname character varying(30),
lname character varying(30),
tel_no character varying(15)
);

create table aud_employee
(
emp_id character varying(10),
fname character varying(30),
lname character varying(30),
tel_no character varying(15)
aud_col_changed character varying(100)
);
```

--

```
insert into employee values('215','Mark','Cooper','222-458-254');
```

This will also result to insert the record in an audit table through trigger and will have null value in aud_col_changed column.

Now when I update the same record :-

```
update employee set tel_no='255-458-254' where emp_id='215';
```

So, audit would also be created for this update made and audit table should now consist another record and would consist value 'tel_no' in aud_col_changed column.

If there are multiple columns changed at a time, it would be separated by comma in same field.

If this is the right approach, could you please describe the ways of achieving it?

**Please note that the table on which I am trying to implement this approach has around 18 columns out of whih 6-7 columns are JSON.**

Comment: EventSourcing might be a better solution to your use case.... (research around, its quite popular)

Comment: That looks good but body column in event table would look like junk as I have a huge table with multiple columns and with 6-7 columns as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and I found that if we want to store column name then that data needs to be updated through function. In function we need to check each value passed with NOT NULL. If it appears to be not null then we need to hard code the column name and assign it to the variable. If more values are found which are NOT NULL, then that hard coded column name needs to be appended to main variable until we check all the values passed in function with NOT NULL.
This will definitely degrade performance of DB and making it run after every update is obviously not preferable.

Hence, I will not prefer using audit_col_changed column.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is likely to be fine -- you should specify what you want to do with the audit table.

Personally, I would rather have a table where the audit table was one of the following:

- One row per column changed, with the old value and the new value.
- One row per *row* changed, with all the columns appearing twice, once for the old value and once for the new value.

In other words, I usually want to see both the old and new values together.

The first method is tricky when dealing with columns that have different types.  The second is tricky when you want to modify the structure of the table.